# jQuery div's same height inside row

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery function which should set an height of some div's according to the ".master" height and this for all the ".row" that can be found in the document, like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="master">
      (height: 200px)
   </div>
   <div class="slave">
      (should be set to 200px)
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="slave">
      (should be set to 50px)
   </div>
   <div class="master">
      (height: 50px)
   </div>
   <div class="slave">
      (should be set to 50px)
   </div>
</div>
```

What I've tryed is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".szs-row").each(function() {
        $(this + '.szs-slave').height($(this + ".szs-master").height());
    });
});
```

I know it can be done in simpler (like pure CSS) but I would need a JS solution...

Comment: Why you need JS to solve this? I'm just being curious

Comment: Because there are many more elements inside the .row div with diferent structures... for example:

<div class="row">
   <div class="something">
      <div class="lol">
         <div class="master">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slave">
   </div>
</div>

Comment: And those elements inside the .row div are floating right?

Comment: You should check how to float elements with CSS and "clearfix" the container.

Comment: Tryed by this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 1):

If you have floating elements you need to clear the parent element using a classic hack called clearfix.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Demo: codepen.io/anon/pen/tlicz

The first example is using clearfix, the second one should be the problem you're having and trying to solve with JS.

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row").each(function() {
        var masterHeight = $(this).find('.master').height();
        $(this).find('.slave').height(masterHeight);   
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PcL8k/

Comment: I have added border on the CSS to make it clear, thats why its 202.

Comment: Well that's not the problem, everything shouldn't be the same height.

Comment: Feel free to edit the fiddle if you have a better answer, I am totally open

Comment: Why should i? there's a *Post Your Answe* option too… edit option is there to fix small typos, or formatting, not to fix non-working answers. If it was, then there is no need of a down vote option and there won't be multiple answers for a question, everyone can fix whatever you post, ri8?

Comment: Well, then do you what you want bro. No one is stopping you :)

Comment: fiddle link updated in answer which overcomes the issue suggested by @TilwinJoy

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS table layout properties:

```
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row > div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.row > div.master {
  height: 200px; /* for example */
}
```